# Postgres: Need to match records from two tables based on key value and earliest dates in each table

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with a pretty unique record matching problem within postgres right now. Essentially I have a table (A) with a lot of records in it, including a key value that I need to match on and the date of the record. Then I have this other table (B) that I want to match the first table on that key value. However, there can be multiple of the same 'key values' in both tables. To get around this I need to match the earliest key value from table A to the earliest key value to table B, the second earliest to the second earliest, and so on... However, if table B runs out of key value matches in table B then I want to default to the latest key value match in A, even though something else already matched on it.

My initial thought is to use a something like this on both tables:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY key_value ORDER BY date) AS  rank
```

And then join on the rank and key_value field. However, I'm not exactly sure how to get that default scenario to work with this method. And if records are added to one table and not the other and I try the join again, I feel like it might get out of sync.

My other thought was to use a cursor, but I'm really struggling to see how I'd implement that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

first you need number all your rows, the find the one with matching ranks.

After that match the one without matching to the latest_date

```
with cteA as (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY key_value ORDER BY date) AS  rank
     FROM tableA
), cteB as (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY key_value ORDER BY date) AS  rank
     FROM tableB
), ranked_match as (
    SELECT ctA.*, cteB.*
    FROM cteA 
    LEFT JOIN cteB
      ON cteA.key_value = cteB.key_value
     AND cteA.rank = cteB.rank
), latest_row as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY key_value ORDER BY date DESC) AS  rank
    FROM tableB
)
SELECT *
FROM ranked_match 
WHERE cteB.key_value IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM ranked_match 
JOIN latest_row 
  ON ranked_match.key_value = latest_row .key_value
WHERE cteB.key_value IS  NULL
  AND latest_row .rank = 1
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Will be attempting to implement shortly